# Php operators help needed

Tags: php

I'm from C++ background and newbie in php, somebody please help me with the difference between the two:

```
$totalupdatedrows = (count($rows) == 1 and !isset($rows[0]->updated_by))  ? 0 : count($rows);


$totalupdatedrows = count($rows) == 1 and !isset($rows[0]->updated_by)  ? 0 : count($rows);
```

assume count($rows) = 1 and $rows[0]->updated_by=null. Please see that first one has only one extra wrapper parentheses.

I'm getting correct result from the first statement. I expect to get result of 0 which is the result of the first one and not the second one. I can't figure out the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`and` has lower [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than the ternary operators (`?` and `:`). Therefore, you need to wrap it in parenthesis (`(` and `)`) so it is evaluated first.

Note that if you had used `&&`, you would not need to use the extra parenthesis.

Comment: ?: has the lowest precedence as in C++ but in PHP "and" is even below it. I better use && to be compatible with C++.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the PHP documentation - [Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) `and` is nearly last.

If you change your `and` to `&&` it will sit at a higher order than `?:`